# Non-ASCII, non-Unicode characters in literals

Tags: c, xcode, string-literals

Xcode, iOS project. Some of my sources contain initialized strings with values with non-ASCII characters:

```
const char s[] = "Здесь был Вася";
```

The sources are in codepage Windows-1251; once you tell Xcode that, it has no trouble displaying and editing them. The LLVM compiler, however, gives a warning: "Illegal character encoding in string literal". GCC under older versions of Xcode didn't. On other compilers (MSVC, GCC elsewhere) it's not a problem.

I want the strings to be in CP1251 during runtime; replacing them with UTF-8 strings would require plenty of unnecessary conversion code.

Is there a way to turn it off? Ideally, by telling the compiler that the source is in Windows-1251 and I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -finput-charset?

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html